# Is it safe to store a file with its original name on server in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

I'm using PHP and MySQL for my website. I'm allowing user to upload image file to the server using a form. But I've a small doubt that is it safe to use the same file name as user is having on his/her machine or should I change the file name to some customized name pattern before saving it to the server? Also to the database.

Can someone please guide me in this regard?

If your answer is yes then can you please elaborate me on the risks involved in saving the file with the same name as it is on the server.

If you want any further information from me regarding the issue please do let me know. Thanks in advance. Expecting precious and elaborated replies from you.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably best not to use the original filename on your server, or at least to strip all non-alphanumeric characters and add a unique generated ID, for the following reasons:

#### Unicode characters in filenames

Unicode can make two different strings that look the same but have completely different sets of code points.  This can make it difficult to type a filename, especially if the characters in use are not available on your keyboard.  It could also allow two different files to *appear* to have the same name.

#### OS-specific characters in filenames

Linux, as an example, allows pretty much any character in filenames except `/` and `\0` (ASCII NUL).  That means you can have filenames with colons in them (and other surprising characters like '\n'), that cannot (or at least should not) be saved on a Windows system.  So if your server is running on Windows, your users will get an error if they upload a filename with a colon.

These uncommonly used characters can also have some of the problems described above for Unicode characters.

#### Filename collisions

You might have different users that upload files with the same names.  You can mitigate this problem by giving each user their own directory and/or appending a unique ID to each file.

#### Not necessarily the original filename anyway

The original filename field in an HTTP upload can be manipulated by an attacker to be longer than the maximum filename length of your operating system, or otherwise be potentially harmful or confusing.

Comment: simple and clean answer

Answer (score 0):

If you expose the file to the public or even not (assume someone gets access to your server) everybody can gather information out of the file name. So if someone uploads a portrait picture of him/herself and it's named with his/her name. Everybody which can access the file knows that "John Doe" is on that picture (assuming that file name is something like `John_Doe_portrait_small.jpg`).

So I would generate a new filename if this is the case. An example is a social network where users upload files and don't care and probably don't know or are willing to know how they are stored in the filesystem and delivered to the clients afterwards.

For example you could genereate a new filename like this:

```
$newFilename = 'image-' . uniqid() . '.' . $extension_of_uploaded_file;
```

Or use the databses primary key as filename. There are lot of possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

I can speak only from my experience with storing files (and corresponding) file names - so: that is my opinion.

Normally I generate dynamic filenames by hashing timestamp and a random and check if in the destination directory there's no file named like that. If there should be a file named with the new filename the process is repeated until there is a unique filename for that directory.

Apart from that I'm generating directories based on current date where the files are stored (eg. path for todays images might be `images/2014/07/21/1010dea40065a75964f312ac92cc0cf8246f3c7e.jpg`).

In database I have a table with following fields:

> **id** - unsigned int - auto increment
>   **uploadtime** - unsigned int
>   **originalFilename** - varchar(200) *stores original filename*
>   **filePath** - varchar(255) *path to destination file*
>   **filesize** - unsigned int

Answer (score 0):

Well. There is SQL injection. Something like that can be done with file names. Few examples:

```
`rm *`
&& rm *
> something
'; DELETE FROM x WHERE 1 = 1; UPDATE x SET y = '7
```

The next issue is using safe but fancy names. Lets look at the hair space, U+200A.

If You want to deal with problematic strings...